# Rails doesn't execute create.js via Ajax in native JavaScript Vanilla

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Using Rails 4 and native Javascript (Vanilla). I have the following code to create a Shop record via Ajax. The record creates successfully, but refuses to fire `create.js` correctly.

Weird behavior is that on Chrome it says `Rendered shops/create.js.erb` but done nothing, but on Firefox, it says `ActionView::MissingTemplate`.

I also notice that the request is processed as HTML, if that's the issue.

```
# shops_controller.rb
class ShopsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @day_id = params[:day_id]
    shop_details = JSON.parse(shop_params[:shop]).with_indifferent_access
    @shop = Shop.find_or_create_by(source_id: shop_details[:shop_id])
    @shop.save
  end

  private

  def shop_params
    params.permit(
      :shop,
      :day_id
    )
  end
end


# global.js
function addShop(dayId, shop) {
  var shopJSON = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(shop));
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "/shops", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", CSRF.token());
  xhr.send("shop=" + shopJSON + "&day_id=" + dayId);

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
      if (xhr.status != 200) {
        alert('not ok');
      }
    }
  };
}

# app/views/shops/create.js.erb
alert('good');


# Firefox Log

Started POST "/shops" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-01-08 13:11:36 +0800
Processing by shopsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"shop"=>"...", "day_id"=>"85"}
  Shop Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `shops`.* FROM `shops` WHERE `shops`.`source_id` = 'ChIJHbeh32U6K4cR-lP5hY96smc' LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (3.6ms)  INSERT INTO `shops` (`source_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('...', '2017-01-08 05:11:36', '2017-01-08 05:11:36')
   (0.8ms)  COMMIT
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 34ms (ActiveRecord: 8.1ms)

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template shops/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/abc/Sites/powerapp/app/views"
  * "/Users/abc/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.2.0/app/views"
):
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/path_set.rb:46:in `find'


# Chrome Log:
Started POST "/shops" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-01-08 13:13:08 +0800
Processing by shopsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"shop"=>"...", "day_id"=>"79"}
  Shop Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `shops`.* FROM `shops` WHERE `shops`.`source_id` = 'ChIJASFVO5VoAIkRGJbQtRWxD7w' LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (9.2ms)  INSERT INTO `shops` (`source_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('...', '2017-01-08 05:13:08', '2017-01-08 05:13:08')
   (0.6ms)  COMMIT
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered shops/create.js.erb (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 44ms (Views: 25.1ms | ActiveRecord: 10.7ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Action type Javascript response such as `create.js.erb`, `update.js.erb`, `destroy.js.erb` only works with UJS. Here's what I modified to get it working:

- Wrap everything in a form, and add `remote: true` to get UJS support
- Submit form using the following function:

```js
// native Javascript Vanilla
function ujsSubmit(form) {
  var event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
  event.initEvent("submit", true, false);
  form.dispatchEvent(event);
}

// jQuery
$(form).trigger("submit");
```